# can't find apache 408 in logs

Tags: apache2, logs

I have logwatch report thousands of HTTP requests with a request url of "null" to have resulted in a 408 error. But I can't find them in any of my logs.

I tried

```
cd /var/log/apache2
grep "HTTP/1\.1. 408" *
```

and

```
grep 'HTTP/1\.1" 408" *
```

Conversely

```
grep "HTTP/1\.1. 200" *
```

shows results.

Any idea how to find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things:

1. the client may not have send the http string, so grep for '" 408 ' instead: `grep '" 408 ' *access.log`
2. you're not grepping .gz files, zo use something like: `zcat *access.log.*.gz | grep '" 408 '.`
3. You don't search subdirectories, so try adding -r or -R to grep.

Comment: Couple of points, you don't need `zcat`+`grep`, you have `zgrep` for that..`grep -r` will not follow the symlinks by default while `grep -R` will..